# Forbid managing lists

Tags: trello

Is it possible to make nobody except board admin able to add and remove lists? I want users to be able to do everything with cards however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently not possible using the Trello permission system. They only expose options to customize who can create a board, invite, comment and vote. You can see the details on this [Trello support page](http://help.trello.com/article/791-changing-permissions-on-a-board).